# Falcon Olympic decal

Tags: vintage, decals

Looking for help in deciphering what this decal reads? [image]

Answer (score 1):

It says Harrods (which doesn't have much to do with bicycles).

The text is a bit worn, but you can compare it to the logo at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrods.

Comment: Thanks very much. Guessing that's where the bike was originally sold.

Comment: I'd guess it was a sticker someone put on the bike on a whim. Shops that sell bikes usually put the shop sticker on the lower front of the seat tube, not the top of the top tube.

Comment: Harrods, the big store in London sold (and probably still sells) their own branded goods. This could well be a re-branded bike they have had made by some other British company.

Comment: Based on the title, I'd make the wild guess this bike was sold as Falcon Olympic.